# Make clang-format close templates in new line

Tags: c++, templates, clang-format

I have this in my code,

```
template<
    typename Ptr = byte*,
    typename Diff = typename std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::difference_type
> 
struct block;
```

How do I prevent `clang-format` to reflow this as:

```
template<
    typename Ptr = byte*,
    typename Diff = typename std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::difference_type>
struct block;
```

This is my configuration file so far:

```
---
Language:        Cpp
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent  # Align
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: No  # Yes
ColumnLimit:     0
FixNamespaceComments: true
AccessModifierOffset: -99  # 2
IndentWidth:     100
PenaltyBreakTemplateDeclaration: 10
PointerAlignment: Left
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false # true
TabWidth:        100
UseTab:         Always  # Never
...
```

I am using `clang-format 14.0.0`.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference yet...

Comment: @lorro, hehe, good catch. Corrected.

Comment: Found the option `BlockIndent` but currently it says: "

Warning

Note: This currently only applies to parentheses.
"  https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Comment: `BlockIndent` doesn't work for templates, so did you find a solution?

Comment: @Aidan, no solution yet. I have two major nags from clang-format that never seems to get quite right, indentation of template parameters (`< ... >`) and indentation of nested list elements `{ ... }`.

Comment: @Aidan, the note changed in clang-format 18 to "This currently only applies to braced initializer lists (when Cpp11BracedListStyle is true) and parentheses." but no mention of angle bracket yet.